# How did the following commands get me in detached head state?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit

I've done some reading to try and understand how someone gets themselves into a detached head state (generally by trying to check out a commit and not a branch), but I'm unclear as to how my set of commands has ended up causing a detached head state (and would also like to know how I can keep the changes made on this branch/commit and move them to another branch that I can push). I ran the following:

`git checkout - Feature/admin-dashboard` - initially i forgot to add the `b` after the dash, so then I ran:

`git checkout -b Feature/admin-dashboard`

Running `git reflog`, the last 3 logs show the following:

```
ffc971a (HEAD, origin/feature/admin-dashboard, feature/admin-dashboard) HEAD@{0}: commit: Initial work
5a7a34b (master) HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from master to Feature/admin-dashboard
5a7a34b (master) HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from feature/email to master
```

I'm not really sure what this is telling me though, or how to get any useful information from it. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why do you think you're in detached head state or what errors do you get?

Comment: The reflog seems to indicate you are on your branch, and you made a commit. Hence @DelenaMalan's question